# Can I attach a GUI process to a "surrogate X server"?

Tags: x11, xorg, gui, process-management

I have been in a situation where my desktop has crashed and become unresponsive. (In my case it was the Cinnamon DE, and I have yet to try `cinnamon --replace` from the commandline, BTW)

I was using a download manager type GUI app to download a large file, and it was clear that the process was still running quite happily even though the GUI was borked. If I killed X I would kill all the child processes and be forced to restart my download etc.

Is it possible to create a surrogate X session, detach existing GUI processes and hitch them to the "dummy" session, restart the real X session and finally re-hitch the GUI process back to the new, healthy X session? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, a program that loses its connection to the X server could just try reconnecting until a new X server is available.  In fact, I've written programs that do this.  It requires extra code, because you have to re-run your GUI-initialization routine to re-create your resources (windows, bitmaps, fonts, etc) on the new X server, and refresh all your program's internal data structures to use these new resources.

Sadly, almost no X program I've ever seen is willing to do this.  They just crash out because all the reconnect/re-setup is too much trouble.  And more sadly, they can't be tricked into switching X servers because that code to re-init their graphic resources **doesn't exist** in that program.  So for most programs, they're doomed if they lose the X connection.

As XTaran mentioned, there is a neat relay/shim/proxy program called ''xpra'' which acts like an X server to clients, and then can do the re-initialization of their resources into any other X server, allowing you to move all the programs between X servers like you wanted.  When I used it 10 years ago, it had a lot of bugs.  I'm sure they've made  progress since then, but you'll need to find out whether its stable enough for everyday desktop use.

Answer (score 1):

`x0vncserver` (in Debian and Ubuntu in the package `vnc4server`) may help to regain access to crashed or at least no more accessible X session, e.g. with `x0vncserver display=:0`.

And then there is [xpra](http://xpra.org/) which *allows the user to view remote X applications on their local machine, and disconnect and reconnect from the remote machine without losing the state of the running applications* according to Debian's xpra package description.

Maybe one of two tools does help (if the help isn't too late).